# Is $(3n)^{3n}+(1-3n)^{3n-1}$ always squarefree?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For $n$ a positive integer, is the expression
$$(3n)^{3n}+(1-3n)^{3n-1}$$
always squarefree?

I would be interested in seeing a proof of this (if it is actually true) or a counterexample  (if one exists).

(So far I have only checked up to the case $n=22$, and each has been squarefree to this point.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that $$59^2 \mid (3 \cdot 113)^{3 \cdot 113} + (1 - 3\cdot 113)^{3\cdot 113-1}$$ so the $113^{\text{th}}$ number in the sequence is not squarefree. (This is simply a brute-force calculation modulo $59^2$.)

It's interesting that $59$ is the smallest prime whose square can potentially divide $(3n)^{3n} + (1-3n)^{3n-1}$ (the next few are $79, 83, 179$).